# passing bash variables to expect script or scripting expect from inside bash

Tags: networking, macos, bash-scripting, sshfs, expect

This script is intended to mount the contents of my server at home as a read/writeable drive in mac os. Unfortunately due to the fact that my house has a dynamic public ip address, the ip address of the server changes from time to time. my solution is to make the script function by reading the ip address from a file. I had everything working when I was just using an expect script, but I was unable to figure out how to read the variable from my file in expect, and when I rewrote the expect script inside of bash it stopped working. here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/Users/cm4nxd/Library/Scripts/current.ip
ipaddress=$(<"$file")

/usr/bin/expect <<EOD

spawn sudo sshfs -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new cm4nxd@$ipaddress:/ /Volumes/ryzen-server -oallow_other -oauto_xattr -ovolname=ryzen-server
expect "*?assword:"
send "password\r"
expect eof

EOD

echo 'yes' >> /Users/cm4nxd/Library/Scripts/done.info
```

Answer (score 1):

1. pass the value through the environment:

   ```bsh
   ipaddress=$(<"$file")
   export ipaddress

   /usr/bin/expect <<'EOD'

   spawn sudo sshfs -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new cm4nxd@$env(ipaddress):/ /Volumes/ryzen-server -oallow_other -oauto_xattr -ovolname=ryzen-server
   # ..........................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   (edit 17 hours later) -- Note that the `'EOD'` **must be quoted**. That essentially single quotes the entire heredoc so that the shell does not expand Expect's variables.
2. don't need the shell: read the file in expect

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env expect

   set fh [open /Users/cm4nxd/Library/Scripts/current.ip r]
   gets $fh ipaddress
   close $fh

   spawn ... user@$ipaddress ...
   ```

Comment: 3. pass the value as a command line parameter to the expect script. Probably the most obvious method :)